# Detect back button in browser when the user go back to original page

Tags: javascript

I have a page that hides the query string parameter on load by using the pushState method in javascript. For example this is the original url,

```
www.iprocess.com?acsn=23423432423432434;
```

what it does is it hides the acsn parameter on load. so it looks like this

```
 www.iprocess.com
```

problem is when I click a link inside that page and then goes back to that page it only read www.iprocess.com without the query string parameter so the data does not load.

What I want is if the user go back to that page it loads the query String parameters at the same time hides it.

This the code:

```
 window.history.pushState('currentpage', 'Title', window.location.pathname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `pushState`, use [`replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History#Methods), this way it won't keep the parameter state in history.

Note really easy to make a live example, but [here is a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dgqvePSemGdxBzgtIoCB?p=preview).
Please open the *windowed mode* (<sub>[image: "Launch the preview in a separate window" icon]</sub> in the top right corner)